# WP Query foreach loop - repeats the same post

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I have spent hours on this - hoping someone who knows a bit of PHP can solve it painlessly.

I have a Wordpress query loop which needs to be concatenated together. It kind of works, but I have requested 6 posts, and all 6 are the same!

Here's the code snippet which returns the duplicate posts:

```
////* New tab *//////

$args = array( 'numberposts' => 6, 'orderby' => 'post_date' );
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
$content .= '<div class="tab" id="new"><ul>';

foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post);

  $content .= '<li><a href="' .  get_permalink() . '"</a>' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';

endforeach; 

$content .= '</ul></div>';
return $content; // prints all the contents stringed together
```

This code produces this list:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/xNyvE0w.png]

Any help appreciated...at all! Thanks.

Comment: So what is your question? Why is it giving you 6 things? First off, are there actually 6 things expected to be returned, or are you saying you are expecting a duplicate to only show once? My guess is that since you asked `get_posts()` for 6 things, it gave you 6 things. It looks like it is up to you to check for duplicates.

Comment: Do you do have duplicates, or do you have six or more different posts?

Comment: Yeah the loop is producing the most recent post, but 6 times.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to get the recent posts, not the same one multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code example is taken from inside a function.

**a)** Please try this:

```
// ... cut ...
global $post;  
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 6, 'orderby' => 'post_date' );
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
$content .= '<div class="tab" id="new"><ul>';
foreach ( $postslist as $post ) :  setup_postdata( $post );
    $content .= sprintf( '<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>',  
                          get_permalink(),
                          get_the_title() );
endforeach; 
$content .= '</ul></div>';
wp_reset_postdata();
return $content; // prints all the contents stringed together
```

where I added the `global $post` declaration so `setup_postdata( $post )` can modify the global `$post` object.

**b)** Or try this:

```
// ... cut ...
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 6, 'orderby' => 'post_date' );
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
$content .= '<div class="tab" id="new"><ul>';
foreach ( $postslist as $post ) :
    $content .= sprintf( '<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>',  
                          get_permalink( $post->ID ),
                          get_the_title( $post->ID ) );
endforeach; 
$content .= '</ul></div>';
return $content; // prints all the contents stringed together
```

where I used the post id as an input argument for `get_permalink()` and `get_the_title()`.

**c)** You can also use the raw post title: `$post->post_title` or if you want to take it through the `the_title` filter with:

```
echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $post->post_title );
```

**So to wrap it up:**

Notice that `get_the_title()` is based on `get_post()`, and if you don't use an input argument, then it will try to use the global `$post` object:

```
if ( empty( $post ) && isset( $GLOBALS['post'] ) )
    $post = $GLOBALS['post'];
```

Therefore you always get the same global post object title (usually from the main query) if you don't modify the global object within the secondary loop.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Birgire. Yes, the first solution worked. It was all in the loop, and yours spat out the most recent ones. Great stuff. Thanks so much for this! Martin